# How to make shared memory in c?

Tags: c, windows, shared-memory

How to share data between applications in c?

I used a temporary file as permanent storage. The client puts in data, the server can read it. The idea is to make it possible to add as many clients as you want. This is purely a research question, not directly related to a real world problem.

Are there better ways to share data between applications?

ipc.h (interprogram communication.h)

```
#ifndef IPC  /* Include guard */
#define IPC

void write_message(int ID);
void read_message();

#endif
```

client.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ipc.h"

int main()
{
    int ID;
    while(1){   

        printf("Please enter ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &ID);
        
        write_message(ID);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "ipc.h"

int main()
{
    
    while(1){

        read_message();
        Sleep(100);
    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ipc.c (contains functions as described in ipc.h)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ipc.h"

void write_message(int ID){

    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");   
        exit(1);             
    }
    fprintf(fp, "ID\t:\t%d\n", ID);
    fclose(fp);
}

void read_message(){

    FILE * fp;
    char c;
    fp = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {  
        exit(1);             
    }
  
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF){
        printf("%c", c);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before posting a question it is expected that basic research has been done. Have you for example entered "C shared memory" or "C inter process communication" into your favourite search engine?

Answer (score 0):

A client-server is one way to do it. You didn't specify the OS but if you're on Windows you can create shared memory pages which can be accessed by multiple processes.

You use the function [CreateFileMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga) with PAGE_READWRITE access to create the file object that's going to be shared. Then you need to map that into memory with [MapViewOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) which returns the buffer shared by processes. The second process follows the same steps using the same name name provided in CreateFileMapping.

Both processes can now read and write to that buffer.